# Implementation of Lanczos method that returns tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, python, iterative-method, eigensystem, krylov-method

The [Lanczos method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) can be used to obtain extremal eigenpairs of sparse symmetric or hermitian matrices. I know there are several implementations of the Lanczos method (as well as Arnoldi, Davidson, and others) out there, but I am specifically interested in one that returns the tridiagonal matrix, *not just the eigenvalues and eigenvectors*. The way I am doing this now is using my own Lanczos implementation in Fortran. Is there a maintained library that does the same efficiently, preferably in python?

Comment: It appears that SLEPc will soon provide this functionality: https://gitlab.com/slepc/slepc/-/merge_requests/33